# How best to sync server scripts with an SVN, when the server can't directly access the SVN

Tags: windows-server-2012, svn

I have a set of servers, that due to corporate firewall rules, can not directly access my SVN server.

We are making an attempt at better code control, so we are starting to put our scripting (perl) in SVN along with everything else.

I would like to be able to -

1. Roll out latest production approved scripts and executables from my SVN to my server.
2. Sync server to SVN (eg, test in QA, sync to SVN, roll out to prod)
3. Validate my server matches the code in the SVN.

I can access the (Windows 2012) servers via RDP.

I'd like to have a tool that would allow me to easily roll out new code to all of my servers and validate that everything is on the latest version.

Obviously this would be easy if I could just do this right on the servers! But I can't.

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this website is about managing information technology systems in a business environment, the only acceptable solution would be confronting your system engineer about those firewall rules, that block your SVN. If there is a reason for them (i.e. to prevent source code leakage), you should ask to add exceptions for you (i.e. to do better code control). You shouldn't just create workarounds of those policies, since it will harm security/managementability and stability of the your company's IT-infrastructure.

Try to discuss your problem with system administrator, he should be able to help you out (at least tell him about the "workarounds" if you ever will create them - it's his job to manage those kind of things after all)